# Ход загрузки операционной системы (Debian 7.4) в первом окне консоли стирается

Tags: загрузка

ход загрузки операционной системы (Debian 7.4) в первом окне консоли стирается и его можно посмотреть через dmesgно как сделать, так чтобы после загрузки он так и оставался

Comment: А что не так? Ход загрузки на первой консоли и должен стираться, если загрузка произошла нормально. А затем - приглашение на tty1!

Answer (score 1):

После загрузки и появления ввода логина, просто нажимайте Shift+PageUp